# Is it possible to connect a Nodejs server to multiple VPN?

Tags: vpn

We are trying to connect a Nodejs server to multiple SQL databases. The problem is that every SQL Server database is in a different network with a different VPN. Is it possible to connect one server to these three machines? [Our scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbnNv.png)

Comment: What oe this even have t odo with Node.js or sql server? Routing and VPN are handled on OS level, there is nothing SQL Server or Node.JS specific in setting up VPN or routing tables.

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't know if it was relevant or not. I am not a network professional and I don't know a lot of things, that's why I used to ask. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This is a place for pro admins - end ser or "me not know way around... superuser.com - they will teach you the basics of networking any programmer should know.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about that.

Comment: NP. Note that your problem CAN actually be brutally complicated if multiple databases seem to use the same network configuration - actually impossible if they are on the same (internal) IP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, and even easy as long as the IP ranges don't overlap. That's normal routing for you; Longest prefix wins.